# Rails 3 time zone issue (database is 5 hours off)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timestamp

So in my rails console. This is what I get if I check Time.now:

```
1.9.2p290 :014 > Time.now
 => 2012-02-06 01:00:43 -0500 
1.9.2p290 :015 > Time.now.zone
 => "EST"
```

In my application.rb I have set the time zone as follows:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

However, when I store something into the database, it is still 5 hours off:

```
1.9.2p290 :011 > event = Event.new(:message => 'blah', :status_id => 1, :service_id => 1, :created_at => Time.now)
 => #<Event id: nil, message: "blah", status_id: 1, service_id: 1, created_at: "2012-02-06 05:55:26", updated_at: nil>
```

Why is it five hours off? If I compare the zones of each, this is what I get:

```
1.9.2p290 :016 > event.created_at.zone
 => "EST" 
1.9.2p290 :017 > Time.now.zone
 => "EST"
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I fixed the issue. Looks like this line in application.rb was causing a problem.
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

ActiveRecord will use the local time zone by default according to the ActiveRecord::Timestamp docs. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

in AR 3.2.1, you must either set this option to :utc or :local, or you will receive this warning:

warning: :database_timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local